I'm trying to remember a game about collecting a lot of gold and defeating bosses

I remember very little about this game. All I remember is that you defeat enemies to collect gold (I know, very generic). There are bosses as well and you can upgrade stuff. I think the big skull on the left is a boss, and the little skulls are enemies, and the building-shaped things are shops of some kind.
I think it was played in a web browser. I don't think you need to download anything to play it.

A Google Image search indicates it's Ginormo Sword according to this article.
It might be playable here (haven't tried myself).
